# Unknown notation for image of linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, linear-transformations

Today I came across this notation:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $\mathbb{F}$, let $\phi:V\to V$ be a linear map and $\alpha\in \mathbb{F}$. Show that (some property) holds for $V(\alpha, \phi)$.

I have never come across the notation $V(\alpha,\phi)$ so far but my guess is that it has something to do with the image.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the context given? It might be of importance what precisely *some property* is.

Comment: In Hoffman and Kunze, a similar notation is used to denote the $\phi$-invariant subspace generated by $\alpha$ (where $\alpha$ is a vector rather than a scalar).